# Trigger a function when any property of an object changes with RxPy

Tags: python-3.x, reactive-programming, rx-py

In RxPy, is there anything similar to `INotifyPropertyChanged` in .NET framework mentioned [here](https://github.com/LeeCampbell/RxCookbook/blob/master/Model/PropertyChange.md)? I'm trying to add an observer to an object, so that any property of the object changes, a function will be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._my_attr = None
        self.property_changed = Subject()
    ...
    @property
    def my_attr(self):
        return self._my_attr

    @my_attr.setter
    def my_attr(self, value):
        if value != self._my_attr:
            self._my_attr = value
            self.property_changed.on_next(('my_attr', value))

a = A()
a.property_changed.subscribe(print)
a.my_attr = 1
a.my_attr = 3
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this for literal variables like variables holding string, list, or dictions - dictions more specifically.

Comment: It's kind of amazing ReactiveX for Python doesn't support detecting changes to properties considering that is the entire purpose of functional reactive programming.